# Don't see default SharePoint Workflows in share point online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, approval-process

I have created a modern Site in SharePoint Online tenant. Now I want to run the an approval workflow over my document library. When I open the site using SharePoint Designer I don't see any Default workflows which is provided by SharePoint.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks,
Kailash

Comment: Note that as currently advised, SP2010 workflows will be disabled permanently on 1 Nov, 2020.  See announcement: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use default approval workflow, you do not need to use SharePoint Designer. They are built in workflows and cannot be modified. You can follow this to add a built-in approval workflow:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72_i9wcZZd4

If you use SharePoint Designer, you can create a custom approval workflow. Here is an example:https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

And of course you can search google with keyword like `"SharePoint designer approval workflow step by step"` for more reference.

Comment: I reactivated the "Workflow" SC feature, still don't see the OOTB- Approval Workflow.
I am only able to see the "Disposition Approval" and "Three-State" workflow. Nothing else is displaying.

FYI: The site is a modern site.
Please help me on this.

Thanks